# Why is IntelliJ telling me this variable has not been initialized?

Tags: java, variables, exception, inner-classes

I am working on a class with an inner class

My code:

```
package com.solignis;
public class Config {
    public static final Target target;
    class Target {
        public void create(String targetName) {    
            System.out.println("Created" + targetName);   
        }

        public void destroy(String targetName) {    
            System.out.println("Destroyed" + targetName);    
        }
    }    
}
```

IntelliJ doesn't see anything wrong with the subclass but it keeps complaining that I have not initalized the static variable `target`. But when I try to initialize it with something like `null` I get a null pointer exception (no surprise there!) but I don't what I could initialize the variable with since as far I can understand all its just an instance of the Target subclass in the Example superclass (is this right?). Also `Target` has no constructor so I cannot declare `new` on `target` in order to initialize the variable.

So what could I do?

Please correct me if I am incorrect about my understanding of this I am still trying to wrap my head around the more "deeper" workings of Java.

Comment: If you don't define a constructor for a class, there will be a default no-args constructor.

Comment: It is a surprise that you can't initialize it with null. There is a problem in you program logic. This is not a java/intellij problem

Comment: I know its a problem with my logic but I am not sure what. I was more stating that intellij is complaining about it.

Comment: Oh oops, that what I get for not copying and pasting my actual code in. The example I wrote was done specifically for this post. One sec.

Comment: @Solignis Now your question and code does not make any sense.

Comment: You probably want the target class to be static, so you can create an instance without an having an instance of Config. Then it would be possible to build a target using, the `create()` method. You can create a Target to use as input to the Config constructor. I do not know what you plan, but in most cases I would also advice against making the Target variable static. The reason is that it makes no sense to have a Config class if the target applies for all Configs (I guess and also since Config is not static). I might have misunderstood things, but you should look one more time at your design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `test` is indeed not initialized:
`public static Test test;`

Initialization means putting value into the variable, i.e. something like this: `test = SOMETHING;`

The SOMETHING may be either `null` or an instance of the type of the variable. In your case:

```
test = null;
test = new Test();
```

are valid expressions.

Indeed if you put null to the `test` you cannot "use" it, i.e. invoke its method or access its member variables.

BTW. `Test` is not a subclass of `Example` as probably you think. It is its inner class. Subclass is a class that extends other class. Actually `Test` is a direct subclass of object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the subclass vs inner class.

Answer (score 1):

in fact you can initialize a class that you do not declared a constructor for it
it has a default constructor with no argument

```
    test = new Test();
```